# Python mammoth error: zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python-3.x, mammoth

My code is ran in Python 3.8.2, name of file is `main.py`

[image]

After I run `python main.py`, i receive the error like this:

[image]

My path to file is : `C:\Users\84165\Desktop\KLTN-backend\upload\thainq\Test.docx`

I have searched in stackoverflow for hours about this error, but there is no solution.

Am i wrong in somewhere?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This error usually happens when you use `r` instead of `rb` when we do `with open` the file. But, it looks like you are already using `rb`. Did you try hardcoding the file path? Also, try a different input file.

Comment: @JintoLonappan i used "rb" as open file as binary file followed by mammoth docs. I tried hardcoding the path but nothing changes

Comment: I tried your exact code and I got the result. See below: ```/code/python/testers/upload/thainq/Test.docx
<p>This is a test DOCX file</p><p>To verify the mammoth package in Python</p>
None``` . Try creating a new virtual environment and re-install mammoth. Sorry, not sure how else to help

Comment: @JintoLonappan i've created an issue on this github package. Maybe i'm wrong in somewhere. Thank you for spending time!

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons this may be happening

1. Your docx file is completely empty (0 bytes).
2. The docx file your code is operating on through `mammoth.convert_to_html` or `mammoth.extract_raw_text` is currently open. Please close your file, then run the script.